# DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH failing to execute on Windows 7 C++

Tags: c++, dll, windows-7, messagebox, loadlibrary

I am trying to load a `.dll` file and have it display a message box when loaded. From my understanding, once a `.dll` is loaded, it makes a call to `dllmain()` and switches to the `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` option. I have written the code for both the `.dll` and the `.exe` which loads it. The `.exe` can load it correctly and print out the address in which the dll has been loaded, but I do not see a message box being displayed. I read somewhere on Microsoft.com that the dll enters a "lock" when loaded as to prevent certain functions or code from being executed for security purposes. Is this feature blocking a message box from being displayed? Is there a work around such as elevated privileges, system, etc...? I am not sure if DEP has any effect either, I have it set to only protect critical Windows processes.

The calling process:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    HMODULE hDll = LoadLibraryA("dll.dll");
    if (hDll == NULL)
        std::cerr << "Unable to load dll";
    else
        std::cout << "Dll loaded @ " << hDll;
    FreeLibrary(hDll);
}
```

The dll file:

```
#include <windows.h>
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            MessageBox(NULL, "Dll has been loaded.", "Loaded", MB_OK);
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

I think it might help me if I had a way to run the `.dll` though a debugger and see what `MessageBox()` returned, but I am not sure how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Just guessing here, but you *don't actually do anything* with the DLL apart from "Load" it in name -- you might find that Windows lazily calls `DllMain` the first time you do something substantial with the library.

Comment: @coolcoder: You're right that using a debugger would help.

Answer (score 5):

Raymond Chen has something to say about this in his blog entry titled [Some reasons not to do anything scary in your DllMain](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/27/63401.aspx?Redirected=true):

> And absolutely under no circumstances should you be doing anything as crazy as creating a window inside your DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH. In addition to the thread affinity issues, there's the problem of global hooks. Hooks running inside the loader lock are a recipe for disaster. Don't be surprised if your machine deadlocks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the blog post [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8556885/3501) links to there are several other informative posts about the [loader lock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mgrier/archive/2005/06.aspx) and things [you should](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/04/23/118979.aspx) [not do](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2006/06/15/632502.aspx) [in DllMain](http://blog.barthe.ph/2009/07/30/no-stdlib-in-dllmai/).

In general you should only call functions in kernel32 that don't create threads/windows, use COM or calls LoadLibrary (or other functions involving the loader lock).

A reasonable list of safe things IMHO would be: DisableThreadLibraryCalls, Tls*, InitializeCriticalSection and in your case (for debugging purposes); OutputDebugString